# which way do i use for loading image from photo library?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I had watched a few tutorial for loading image from photo library to tableView cell.

The way they are doing that is little bit odd because they use UIImagePickerController get the image from the photo library, create path for it and save it to NS User Default or CoreData.

So is there a way to retrieve the image path from the photo library and load it directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code.

```
class MyViewController {
    func getImage() {
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
        // Use image here.
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: can i get the image path directly from photo library? because I wanna save the path and load it to my app

Comment: @Vanishadow No you cannot, unless you copy and re-save the image.

Answer (score 0):

You could try ALAssetRepresentation, i'm using the same in Obj-C.